gradle error: "Could not find method useDefaultAndroidSdkVersions() for arguments [] on project"
How to solve this error:
Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Welcome to Gradle 8.3!
Here are the highlights of this release:
- Faster Java compilation
 - Reduced memory usage
 - Support for running on Java 20
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1:
Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-application/android/build.gradle' line: 10
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-application'.
>
Could not find method useDefaultAndroidSdkVersions() for arguments [] on project ':expo-application' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
* Try:
>
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>
Run with
--info
or --debug option to get more log output.
>
Run with
--scan
to get full insights.
>
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
==============================================================================
2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/ExpoModulesCorePlugin.gradle' line: 65
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
>
Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.
* Try:
>
Run with
--stacktrace
option to get the stack trace.
>
Run with --info
or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with
--scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at
https://help.gradle.org
==============================================================================
BUILD FAILED in 1m 16s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

I have tried to reinstall node modules and installed jdk 17again

Make sure that
npm ls expo-modules-core

shows at least version expo-modules-core@1.12.15. If it shows an older version with overridden right next to it, remove that override from your package.json. Either way, run npm upgrade afterwards and try again.
You can confirm you got the right or wrong version by looking into node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/ExpoModulesCorePlugin.gradle. If that doesn't contain a definition for ext.useDefaultAndroidSdkVersions, your version is too old and you will run into the error shown in this post.

Got it fixed running this command :
npx expo install --fix


I've the same problem. It happened over night in my main pc, i use two differents pcs to code, and one of them start having this error.
I've tried do reinstall android studio and my sdk, changing emulator and fix dependencies, but nothing seens to work. What is most odd is that the project works perfect fine in other machine.

uninstalling sentry-expo fixed it for me for some reason

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
